# Show some custom content on image using jquery galleria plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleria

I'm using jquery galleria plugin and it's working fine as it should, but i need some custom content and links that should show in center of image[image: This is what i need]

Is it possible using galleria to show some content in middle of the image ?

please advise me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your requirement can be fulfilled with the `data-layer` option.

```
<img data-big="big.jpg" data-layer="<h2>A title</h2><p>Some content</p>">
```

For more details, here is the [reference](http://galleria.io/docs/references/data/)